# How can you use the AWSELB cookies to also provide auth for your backend application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, cookies, session-cookies, openid-connect

So, I understand how OIDC works for the most part.  I know how to solve this question if we use OIDC directly (without AWS handling it for us).  The browser would just send their `access_token` to us for all async calls, and we could verify it against the OIDC `UserInfo` service that's hosted by our OIDC provider.

The AWS implementation doesn't expose any of these common OIDC values to the browser though, and just gives us their proprietary encrypted cookies like `AWSELB`. This is fine, for super basic sites where you don't care about actually authenticating the user once they're authorized, but we care about both.

We could also generate a proprietary "session key" when our callback is hit, and use that instead of the `AWSELB` cookie...  but it seems like reinventing the wheel.  **Certainly, there must be a way to let our backend application code just reuse the `AWSELB` cookie to verify the identity of user?** AWS documentation mentions no such webservice to allow us to validate that cookie from our server code.

Answer (score 2):

The load balancer provides the IdP's access token as a header: `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken`; you should be able to validate this against the IdP. It also provides user claims in a header: `x-amzn-oidc-data`.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#user-claims-encoding

Comment: The link you provided shows a method of validating the header data (accesstoken and oidc-data) against the ALB.
This means you can rest assured the data is correct. So no need for tinkering with the cookie.

Issue stays that you can't use the data in the headers to auth against another ALB endpoint